# Transparent Emulator showing on android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run my first program on Android Studio 3.0.1. However when i fire up the emulator, it comes transparent and nothing shows up on it.

[image]

Comment: Encountered the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes. In the setting for emulator , select software emulation instead of automatic and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! does work. consider adding this as an answer, and mark it as a solution for other people who run into the same problem

Answer (score 12):

I was able to resolve this problem by changing the emulator settings to software emulation.

`Tools > AVD manager > Edit (Edit icon) >` change `graphics` to `software emulation`. (by default it shows Automatic Emulation )

[image: AVD]
[image: graphics settings]

Comment: This field was grayed out in my emulator. In case anyone else has the same problem the answer of user22289460 worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the above options but then had to apply one more setting for whatever reason.

On the emulator, hit the "..." to get to Extended Controls. Then at the bottom of the drawer is the "Settings". In the general tab, toggle "Show window frame around device" and it no longer became transperrant.

Answer (score 3):

Start virtual device. On the additional panel click button "...", go to Settings, select tab Advanced, change OpenGL renderer, restart virtual device. For me helps ANGLE (D3D11) or "SwiftShader" options

Answer (score 1):

i am able to resolve the same.In the setting for emulator , select software emulation instead of automatic and it worked.Hope it works for all

Comment: Setting found in Android Studio > Tools  > Android > AVD Manager > Editing the desired device > Advanced Settings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NVIDIA GPU and on the same time you have Integrated graphics card, it's possible to experience graphics emulation issues. You can verify which GPU executes current emulation. If it's NVIDIA you can try to select force usage of Integrated GPU:

1. Open Emulator in Android studio
2. Verify you have transparent screen on device
3. Open "NVIDIA Control Panel" Application
4. Go to "3D Settings" -> "Manage 3D Settings" -> Tab "Program Settings"
   [see how screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX8Rn.png) -> Click button "Add" in "1. Select a program to customize" and choose "/qemu_system-x86_x64.exe" -> In "2. Select the preferred graphics processor for this program" set "Integrated graphics"
5. Restart AVD emulator
6. Done

Answer (score 0):

If you use a laptop with optmus technology, try going to device manager and disabling your Intel HD graphics.