# Android - Transparent Emulator Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am having this error where my android emulator is transparent.. I tried restarting my laptop, restarting Android Studio, Deleting the device and making a new one but still no luck! I've seen a question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423514/transparent-emulator-showing-on-android-studio) but there is no step by step instruction on how to do it! and instructions are not clear at least for me can anyone help me? I've been trying to fix this for hours

[image]

again [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423514/transparent-emulator-showing-on-android-studio) is the link to the same question

Comment: Mention the questions you have seen on SO similar to your also mention what steps you have tried. Current information is not sufficient.

Comment: @VicJordan Edited it! please do help if you know the solution I really need it

Comment: found the solution just change the graphics to software instead of automatic

Answer (score 6):

I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION.

First this question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423514/transparent-emulator-showing-on-android-studio) but for me the solution wasn't explained properly so here is a step by step solution to this problem.

**Step 1** 
Go to your Android Virtual Device Manager.

**Step 2** 
In the device manager you will find lists of your emulators and here under action click the pencil option which will open the Virtual Device Configuration.
**Step 3** 
 From here in the Emulated Performance option change the graphics to ***Software*** instead of automatic.

This is the most detail I can explain this and hope to help people who will get the same problem as me will be solved.

Comment: but the play store supported android pie x86 doesnt work as emulated performance is not allowed to change and is set to automatic. What to do in this case as i need the play store supported android pie and i dont have hyper-v as i am running windows home

Comment: found the solution - disable device frame makes it work. Some bug in that